# Diameter of space forms with positive curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following is Exercise 6.7.22 from *Riemannin Geometry* by P. Petersen.

> Use an analog of theorem 6.2.3 to show that any closed manifold of constant curvature $=1$ must either be the standard sphere or have diameter $\leq\pi/2$. Generalize this to show that any closed manifold with $\operatorname{sec}\geq1$ is either simply connected or has diameter $\leq\pi/2$.

Theorem 6.2.3 is Cartan's theorem asserting that an isometry of a simply connected complete manifold of nonpositive curvature which has finite order must have a fixed point. The proof uses the well-known center of mass construction and exploits the convexity of distance functions in nonpositive curvature.

How does this generalize to positive curvature? I have no idea what to do. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure about Cartan's theorem, but iirc you can show using Jacobi fields that a geodesic of length $>\pi/2$ has a length-reducing variation.

Comment: @Kajelad You mean the Bonnet–Myers theorem? That proof only shows that a geodesic with length $>\pi$ admits a length-reducing variation.